# Unable to scrape the text from a certain LI element

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am scraping this [URL](http://www.starwoodhotels.com/lemeridien/property/rooms/index.html?language=en_US&propertyID=1937).

I have to scrape the main content of the page like *Room Features* and *Internet Access*

Here is my code:

```
 for h3s in Column:  # Suppose this is div.RightColumn 
    for index,test in enumerate(h3s.select("h3")):
        print("Feature title: "+str(test.text))
        for v in h3s.select("ul")[index]:
            print(v.string.strip())
```

This code scrapes all the `<li>`'s but when it comes to scrape Internet Access 
I get

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Because `<li>`s data under the *Internet Access* heading is contained inside the double-quotes like *"Wired High Speed Internet Access..."*

I have tried replacing `print(v.string.strip())` with `print(v)` which results `<li>Wired High...</li>`

Also I have tried using `print(v.text)` but it does not work too

The relevant section looks like:

```html
<h3>Internet Access</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Wired High Speed Internet Access in All Guest Rooms
     <span class="fee">
        25 USD per day
     </span>
  </li> 
 </ul>
```

Comment: There are no double-quotes; perhaps you are confused by the view of the element tree in the developer tool of your browser?

Comment: If you inspect in Google Chrome ... you will see double-quotes and no SPAN ...

But in Firefox, no 2ble-quotes and it also shows span

Comment: The span is there in Chrome too, you need to scroll down. The quotes are there *as part of the developer tool* to show how much whitespace (tabs and newlines) are there around the string value. They are not part of the actual value of that element.

Comment: `he quotes are there as part of the developer tool to show how much whitespace` thanks dear ... new info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup elements only have a `.string` value if that string is the *only child* in the element. Your `<li>` tag has a `<span>` element as well as a text.

Use the `.text` attribute instead to extract *all* strings as one:

```
print(v.text.strip())
```

or use the [`element.get_text()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
print(v.get_text().strip())
```

which also takes a handy `strip` flag to remove extra whitespace:

```
print(v.get_text(' ', strip=True))
```

The first argument is the separator used to join the various strings together; I used a space here.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> sample = '''\
... <h3>Internet Access</h3>
... <ul>
...     <li>Wired High Speed Internet Access in All Guest Rooms
...      <span class="fee">
...         25 USD per day
...      </span>
...   </li> 
...  </ul>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(sample)
>>> soup.li
<li>Wired High Speed Internet Access in All Guest Rooms
     <span class="fee">
        25 USD per day
     </span>
</li>
>>> soup.li.string
>>> soup.li.text
u'Wired High Speed Internet Access in All Guest Rooms\n     \n        25 USD per day\n     \n'
>>> soup.li.get_text(' ', strip=True)
u'Wired High Speed Internet Access in All Guest Rooms 25 USD per day'
```

Do make sure you call it on the *element*:

```
for index, test in enumerate(h3s.select("h3")):
    print("Feature title: ", test.text)
    ul = h3s.select("ul")[index]
    print(ul.get_text(' ', strip=True))
```

You could use the `find_next_sibling()` function here instead of indexing into a `.select()`:

```
for header in h3s.select("h3"):
    print("Feature title: ", header.text)
    ul = header.find_next_sibling("ul")
    print(ul.get_text(' ', strip=True))
```

Demo:

```
>>> for header in h3s.select("h3"):
...     print("Feature title: ", header.text)
...     ul = header.find_next_sibling("ul")
...     print(ul.get_text(' ', strip=True))
... 
Feature title: Room Features
Non-Smoking Room Connecting Rooms Available Private Terrace Sea View Room Suites Available Private Balcony Bay View Room Honeymoon Suite Starwood Preferred Guest Room Room with Sitting Area
Feature title: Internet Access
Wired High Speed Internet Access in All Guest Rooms 25 USD per day
```

Comment: li in `Internet Access` does not have any `span` in it sir .... it has text quoted in 2ble-quotes

Comment: @Umair: I copied the relevant section of the page into your question. It very much *does* have the span element in it.

Comment: O yes ... I was inspecting it with Google Chrome and it did not show any `span` ... but FireBug does show that

Comment: I got error `print(v.get_text(' ', strip=True))` results in 
`AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'`

Comment: @Umair: are you sure you are using it on the `<li>` element?

Comment: `print(v.li.get_text(' ', strip=True))` results in
`AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'li'`

Comment: @Umair: `v` is a string, not an element.

Comment: sorry for lack of my knowledge .. can u pls tell me what to do :) ?